DJI Mimo and 360 photography?
I got myself a DJI Osmo Mobile SE, a gimbal for cellphones, which comes with an app (DJI Mimo) that you install on your phone that allows you to manipulate the gimbal.
One feature of the app is that you can use the gimbal to automatically create a 9-photo 'pano', with the photos in a grid, or a 240 degree horizontal pano.
It seems to me it should then not be a technical issue to also be able to shoot 360 degree horizontal photos, or, even better, 360x180 (or close) photo spheres.
But, options for this do not exist in the app.
Is there a way to use a gimbal like this, to, with as much automation as possible, shoot a photo sphere (or close to it)?
Worst case scenario would be that I have to stitch my own photos (like with Hugin), but that the photos are still captured automatically, instead of me having to rotate the camera/gimbal for each image (or each 9-image grid).

From the user manual, the Osmo Mobile SE has the following controllable range (the range you can cover with the camera):

Pan (yaw): -115º to 115º (total: 230º)
Roll: -85º to 160º
Tilt: -43º to 53º (total: 96º)

That's 130º shy on the yaw to cover 360º; and about 84º short of 180º on the tilt. IOW, you can't actually cover a 360ºx180º view. So that's probably why there's no such option.
